# NextJS - On-Demand Revalidation not working with ISR

Tags: next.js, multi-tenant, vercel

I am building a multi-tenant application in NextJS using their Pages router. Using middleware functions we rewrite the pages so it shows the account name or subdomain in the URL like username.company.com or mysubdomain.company.com. This all works great.

The pages where user-generated content is displayed are structured as follows:

```
- Pages  
---- _sites  
-------- [site]
------------ index.tsx
------------ [slug].tsx
```

the [slug.tsx] and index.tsx pages use **getStaticPaths** and **getStaticProps** to render everything on the server during build time, they do not revalidate automatically since I only want them to clear the caching when the user makes updates to the content.

Therefore I follow the documentation to revalidate a path via an API (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation)

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  // Check for secret to confirm this is a valid request
  if (req.body.secret !== process.env.REVALIDATE_TOKEN) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
  }

  try {
    // this should be the actual path not a rewritten path
    // e.g. for "/blog/[slug]" this should be "/blog/post-1"
    await res.revalidate(req.body.url);
    return res.json({ revalidated: true });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send("Error revalidating");
  }
}
```

This is the code I'm using, I know that you need to supply the exact path here like */_sites/company/fullstack-developer/*

There's not a lot of information available in the documentation regarding this function, I tried both calling it locally and on the server with different path types, but it keeps not refreshing the cache so it will always return the same stale content until I build again.

The project is hosted on Vercel, but both locally and on the server manually revalidating does not seem to work properly using NextJS v13.4.13

========
EDIT:

Apparently, you need to call the API function on the hostname you want the changes to be apparent on when using the NextJS middleware functions.

## Got the solution via https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35968